# Offset address for JAL and JALR instrctions in RISC-V

Tags: assembly, riscv

In the RISC-V specification, it is written that the immediates in JAL and JALR instructions are converted to jump offsets as :

1. Sign extend the given immediate to XLEN bits.
2. Set the LSB to zero.

I have a couple of questions regarding this.

**QUESTION 1**

For JAL, this gives a range :

```
000000000000 to 111111111110
```

that is, 4KiB.

Here, if the LSB is going to have to be zero always, why isn't the immediate just considered as the 12 bits before a mandatory zero LSB for the address, hence increasing the range of addresses to:

```
[000000000000]0 to [111111111111]0
```

[ ] represents the given immediate offset, and a zero is added to the end of a given immediate offset internally. That is,

1. Left shift give address by a bit.
2. Sign extend the result to XLEN bits.

**QUESTION 2**

How are positive and negative offsets distinguished from one another? Is the MSB of the given offset used?

Comment: Only even addresses are provided for.  The LSB for an even address is always 0 so it is not encoded.  The encoded value is taken as signed, so is sign extended to 32 or 64 (or 128) bits as needed.

Comment: @ErikEidt So does the immediate value provided in the instruction account for the bits : [12:1] of the address, giving the format of the jump address as 
[sign extension (17 bits)]:[12 bit immediate]:[0]
giving a total of 32 bits?

Comment: JAL has a 21 bit signed range with the LSB not encoded -- it is pc-relative so the target address is `pc:=pc+sxt(imm20 | 0)` where | is concatenation.  JALR has only a 12 signed bit range (with an LSB encoded), where it clears the LSB:  after addition of the register value: `pc:=(rs1+sxt(imm12))&-2` where & is bitwise masking and -2 is a mask that clears the LSB.

Comment: @ErikEidit Thank you, that cleared it up.

Comment: @ErikEidit Also, is there a reason why there is a mask in JAL instead of a concatenation which would increase it's range?

Comment: There's no mask in JAL, its in JALR.  JALR is a register indirect branch, so for most usages doesn't need an offset at all.  It is user for mostly function returns, some indirect function calling (function pointers & vtables) -- neither needs any offset at all.

Comment: @ErikEidt Thank you, it is very clear now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JAL` has a 20 bit offset and a register as operands.

Its operation is `pc := pc + sxt ( imm20 << 1 )`.

As you can see by the formula, the branch is pc-relative.  The immediate can reach +/- 1 MB from the `JAL` itself.  The immediate is shifted by one bit, the true LSB is always zero, so is not encoded.

Because RISC V supports instructions in multiples of 16-bits (two bytes), we cannot assume the next-to-LSB is also zero, as it would be with MIPS (which has 32-bit instructions).

The register operand in `JAL` is optionally used to capture the return address in addition to performing the branch.

`JAL`'s function is to perform modestly far pc-relative branches or calls using its 20-bit range.  (Contrast with RISC V conditional branch instructions that have only have 12 bits for +/- 4 KB range.)

---

`JALR` has a 12 bit offset and two registers as operands.

Its operation is `pc := ( rs1 + sxt ( imm12 ) ) & -2`.

As you can see by the formula, the branch is register indirect, relative to the value in `rs1`.

Like `JAL`, `JALR` can also capture the the return address.

`JALR` is used to return from a function (aka `RET` in assembly.  In this form $ra is used as the source register, and no return address is captured).  This uses zero for the offset (i.e. an offset is not required).

`JALR` is also used to perform indirect function calls: calls via function pointer, virtual method dispatches, etc..   These use also use zero for the offset.

`JALR` can also be used in sequence with `AUIPC`.

---

`AUIPC` has a 20 bit offset and a register as operands.

Its operation is `rd := pc + ( imm20 << 12 )`.

It computes the upper part of a pc-relative immediate (while also providing a lower part of the pc that is not relative).

Combined with `JALR`, this can accomplish a 32-bit pc-relative branch or call.

```
AUIPC r5, labelFarAway      # AUIPC encodes upper 20 bits of label's distance from pc
JALR r5, $ra, labelFarAway  # JALR encodes the lower 12 bits of same
```